# Nokogirl::HTML.parse trying to find a <li> element by its class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I'm trying to get the contents of  elements 
The last line fails for invalid syntax

```
    browser=Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
    doc=Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
    list=doc.css("ul").sort { |x,y| y.css("li").count <=> x.css("li").count }.first
    rows=list.css("class=brand-content")
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the html surrounding the section you want to scrape?

Answer (score 0):

Try `rows=list.css(".brand-content")`.

'css' means it uses CSS selector syntax. `li.brand-content` would also work.

Comment: That returned an empty set The css selector actually looks like this:  <li class="brand-content " data-brand-id="203354270">

Comment: add `puts list` as a temporary diagnostic trace statement. Does it contain what you expect?

Comment: Yes it contains a <ul> with a lot of <li>'s